# running 7-zip from a SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, 7zip

is it possible to call 7-zip from a SQL script? basically i am extracting tables to csv and then packaging them into 7z files. I have installed 7-zip on the machine where SQL Server is installed and added it to the path, but this is not enough it seems.

I get the following error when i try to run the script with xp_cmdshell

```
'7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

this is the code, i have already declared the variables

```
declare @archiveCommand nvarchar(max)
declare @filename nvarchar(max)

set @archiveCommand = '7z a '+@filename+'.7z '+@filename+' '
print @archiveCommand
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @archiveCommand
```

Comment: `added it to the path` where did you add the path?

Comment: Are you sure 7z is in the path for the user user account that runs SQL server?

Comment: Did you restart server after changing PATH?

Comment: You call "exec" from inside the script, right?
Please post the code.

Comment: Why so many answers in comments?

Comment: yeah i added it to the path using the System Properties > Environment Variables. I know it is in the definitely in the path because when i open a new command shell (cmd.exe), and type in 7z.exe and run it, it comes up with the help commands for 7z

Comment: anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: @warzong, different users can have different paths, do you run your cmd.exe as the same user as the sql server?

Comment: @Albin, i am running as the correct user (i.e. my own user). I'm gonna try the suggestion about restarting, that's the only thing i haven't yet tried, since theres processing still going on, but probably will know for sure sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, yes, but probably a bad idea: permissions are often a problem (as you've found out), paths and working directories will trip you up, and building shell commands in SQL is a pain all round. It would be much easier just to use an external script, and run it from a scheduled job or SSIS package.

If you clarify exaclty why and when you want to run the script from SQL then someone may be able to suggest a better approach. I do exactly the same thing using SSIS and Python, for example.

Comment: i am just trying to automate a process so i don't have to run the command manually for each table i am processing. the path issue is not really that much of a problem for me, i can just use absolute paths and avoid that. i can probably do this through an external script but would be nice and impressive to be able to do it within sql server. i am only going to be running this infrequently, so its not really a big deal. if it can't be done without major annoyance, then don't worry, i will just do it the manual way.

Comment: I'm not sure why an external script is "manual"? The script can query the list of tables, build and execute a bcp.exe command for eaach one, and then do the same for 7z.exe. Then you only have to maintain the table list. My personal experience is that working with files and filesystems is such a pain in SQL that it's not worth the bother, but obviously things may be different in your environment.

Comment: sorry i meant manual as in without a script. i think if it is not possible/easy in sql server, i then will just do it manually, which is how i am doing it currently. i am having problems getting sql server to recognise the 7z.exe, it keeps saying it can't see it, even though i have restarted it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will be helpful now, but I came across this issue and solved it by calling the 7z app with the file name.

So instead of:

`set @archiveCommand = '7z a '+@filename+'.7z '+@filename+' '`

You would want:

`set @archiveCommand = '"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z" a '+@filename+'.7z '+@filename+' '`

Comment: +1 Yes very helpful cheers.  Sometimes the obvious evades capture (that sneaky obvious).

Comment: This is the solution - no need to set path etc. Brilliant.

Comment: look for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759331/escaping-command-parameters-passed-to-xp-cmdshell-to-dtexec