# Escaping command parameters passed to xp_cmdshell to dtexec

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I am calling an SSIS package remotely using a stored procedure and a call to xp_cmdshell:

```
declare @cmd varchar(5000)
set @cmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /Rep E /Sql Package /SET \Package.Variables[User::ImportFileName].Value;c:\foo.xlsx'
print @cmd
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

This works fine, however I can not guarantee the variable value (c:\foo.xslx) is not going to contain spaces so I would like to escape that with quotes like below:

```
set @cmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /Rep E /Sql Package /SET \Package.Variables[User::ImportFileName].Value;"c:\foo.xlsx"'
```

But by doing this I get the error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Both of the above commands work fine if executed within cmd.exe so I am guessing that SQL Server is interpreting my double quotes and changing something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into this, it appears you have to use the DOS 8.3 notation with xp_cmdshell e.g. c:\progra~1... and you can only have one set of quotes on the arguments.

To get around this limitation, either use the older DOS notation, or put your code in a batch file instead which will run fine.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/4e7024bb-9362-49ca-99d7-1b74f7178a65

Answer (score 10):

In a nutshell, put `CMD /S /C "` at the beginning, and `"` at the end. In between you can have as many quotes as you like.

Here is how you do it:

```
declare @cmd varchar(8000)
-- Note you can use CMD builtins and output redirection etc with this technique, 
-- as we are going to pass the whole thing to CMD to execute
set @cmd = 'echo "Test" > "c:\my log directory\logfile.txt" 2> "c:\my other directory\err.log" '


declare @retVal int
declare @output table(
    ix int identity primary key,
    txt varchar(max)
)


-- Magic goes here:
set @cmd = 'CMD /S /C " ' + @cmd + ' " '

insert into @output(txt)
exec @retVal = xp_cmdshell @cmd
insert @output(txt) select '(Exit Code: ' + cast(@retVal as varchar(10))+')'

select * from @output
```