# SQL exec command using a string parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to call a system command within a procedure that also carries parameters. I get the following error:

> Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddMSTRUser] 
    @LoginID nvarchar(120), 
    @Country nvarchar(120), 
    @FullName nvarchar(120)
AS
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(max);

    SET @cmd = CONCAT('MASysMgr.exe -w C:\User.smw -l "C:\cache.txt" -p "LoginID=' , @LoginID , '" "Country=',@Country,'" "FullName=',@FullName,'"')

    EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

This is how I call it:

```
EXEC AddMSTRUser @LoginID = 'Ugurcan.Kaya', @Country = 'VHQ', @FullName = 'Ugurcan Kaya'
```

Comment: `varchar(max)` is not allowed, max is `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)`.  And you are only allowed one set of double quotes in the command string. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759331/escaping-command-parameters-passed-to-xp-cmdshell-to-dtexec)

Comment: Print `@cmd` before running, so you can see what it actually generated.

Comment: I would ask do you *really* need to do this within SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu we are using a bi software and writing into its metadata is complicated unless i use different software to call queries.

Comment: You could execute this from outside SQL Server though